# Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?

Tags: asp.net, path, directory, mapping, filesystems

Can anyone explain the difference between `Server.MapPath(".")`, `Server.MapPath("~")`, `Server.MapPath(@"\")` and `Server.MapPath("/")`?

Answer (score 842, accepted):

**Server.MapPath** specifies the relative or virtual path to map **to a physical directory**.

- `Server.MapPath(".")`<sup>1</sup> returns the current physical directory of the file (e.g. aspx) being executed
- `Server.MapPath("..")` returns the parent directory
- `Server.MapPath("~")` returns the physical path to the root of the application
- `Server.MapPath("/")` returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)

*An example:*

Let's say you pointed a web site application (`http://www.example.com/`) to

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot
```

and installed your shop application (sub web as virtual directory in IIS, marked as application) in

```
D:\WebApps\shop
```

For example, if you call `Server.MapPath()` in following request:

```
http://www.example.com/shop/products/GetProduct.aspx?id=2342
```

then:

- `Server.MapPath(".")`<sup>1</sup> returns `D:\WebApps\shop\products`
- `Server.MapPath("..")` returns `D:\WebApps\shop`
- `Server.MapPath("~")` returns `D:\WebApps\shop`
- `Server.MapPath("/")` returns `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot`
- `Server.MapPath("/shop")` returns `D:\WebApps\shop`

If Path starts with either a forward slash (`/`) or backward slash (`\`), the `MapPath()` returns a path as if Path was a full, virtual path.

If Path doesn't start with a slash, the `MapPath()` returns a path relative to the directory of the request being processed.

*Note: in C#, `@` is the verbatim literal string operator meaning that the string should be used "as is" and not be processed for escape sequences.*

*Footnotes*

1. `Server.MapPath(null)` and `Server.MapPath("")` will [produce this effect too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17616488/1185053).

Comment: Excellent. We've been battling with Server.Bloody.MapPath. Thanks

Comment: You will be better off using `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` as it doesn't require `HttpContext`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/944219/3205

Comment: Two questions, as follows:

(1.) Does the ASP Classic version of Server.MapPath work the same way as described above?

AND

(2.) I have an SSD drive that I installed in a server, and it's drive letter is "G:"  The website is on drive letter "E:"  I would like the IMAGES directory (and perhaps others) to reside on the G: drive (for speed), but Server.MapPath returns E: when used in code.  It is already a virtual directory that points to the E: drive.  If I point it to the G: drive, how do I inform Server.MapPath to return the proper drive letter to the IMAGES folder?

Answer (score 25):

Just to expand on @splattne's answer a little:

`MapPath(string virtualPath)` calls the following:

```
public string MapPath(string virtualPath)
{
    return this.MapPath(VirtualPath.CreateAllowNull(virtualPath));
}
```

`MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)` in turn calls `MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, bool allowCrossAppMapping)` which contains the following:

```
//...
if (virtualPath == null)
{
    virtualPath = VirtualPath.Create(".");
}
//...
```

So if you call `MapPath(null)` or `MapPath("")`, you are effectively calling `MapPath(".")`

Answer (score 4):

1) `Server.MapPath(".")` -- Returns the "Current Physical Directory" of the file (e.g. `aspx`) being executed.

Ex. Suppose  `D:\WebApplications\Collage\Departments`

2) `Server.MapPath("..")` -- Returns the "Parent Directory"

Ex. `D:\WebApplications\Collage`

3) `Server.MapPath("~")` -- Returns the "Physical Path to the Root of the Application"

Ex. `D:\WebApplications\Collage`

4) `Server.MapPath("/")` -- Returns the physical path to the root of the Domain Name

Ex. `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot`

Answer (score 0):

Working Example, hope this helps show a way to use MapPath with more than just a "/". We are combining "/" and "~".

1. string lotMapsUrl = "~/WebFS/Transport/Maps/Lots/"; --- just get the
   long URL into a variable
2. string lotMapsDir = Server.MapPath(lotMapsUrl); --- get our full
   physical path to this location
3. string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(lotMapsUrl); --- go grab a list
   of the files from the physical path.