# ASP.net relative paths not working?

Tags: asp.net, relative-path, path

This should be pretty simple but it's not working.

I have a file underneath the root of my project. I want to call it like this.

```
GetWorkbook("tplBud806_wRevenue.xls")
```

I publish the project out to the server and try to run it and the server says it can't find it.

```
Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\tplBud806_wRevenue.xls'.
```

That's not the path it should be taking. It should be under E:\IIServer\rootwww\reports\tplBud806_wRevenue.xls.

I thought relative paths were supposed to start from the path that the project was running in. I've also tried.

```
GetWorkbook("/tplBud806_wRevenue.xls")
GetWorkbook("\tplBud806_wRevenue.xls")
GetWorkbook("~/tplBud806_wRevenue.xls")
GetWorkbook("~\tplBud806_wRevenue.xls")
```

Is there some setting I'm missing? It's got to be something simple...

Comment: Do you want people to be able to get to the file directly via a URL?  If not, you probably want to put it in App_Data instead of the root of your website.

Comment: I don't really care if they get this file, it's a test project right now. But thanks for the heads up because this will be production eventually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
GetWorkBook(Server.MapPath("tplBud806_wRevenue.xls"));
```

Comment: And for the explanation, see the answer by John Weldon.

Comment: For MVC users that came across this solution, check this question for another method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616646/specifying-relative-file-location-in-web-config-for-use-by-standard-c-sharp-clas

Answer (score 3):

`GetWorkbook` is not an ASP.NET function, and it likely defaults to the folder that the process calling it was started from.  The process in this case is an IIS process and probably started in that folder.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm not as familiar with ASP.net so this is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Server.MapPath?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is running in an AppDomain loaded by the w3wp.exe located in the directory in your error. Which means that trying to look for any file will start in that directory. You should use [Page.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.mappath.aspx), as mentioned by others. It tells the application to start looking in the folder your aspx is in.

Answer (score 1):

`GetWorkBook(Server.MapPath("~/tplBud806_wRevenue.xls"));` If the .XLS file is at the root of your project.

You can use also use `~` in conjuction with ResolveURL() to access an URL in your site. So `~` will be replaced by the root URL of your project

**Example:**

`ResolveURL("~\tplBud806_wRevenue.xls")`

will be transformed to
`http://myproject.url/website/tplBud806_wRevenue.xls`

If you need disk access, like in your example, use `Server.MapPath`

Look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath) to learn more about `Server.MapPath`