# Specifying relative file location in web.config for use by standard C# class library

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm struggling to find a way of specifying a file location in `web.config` appSettings that avoids using hard-coded paths but allows a non-'web aware' C# library to find a file.

The C# library uses standard `File.Open`, `File.Exists` methods, etc. to operate on a data file, which is stored in my web application (ASP.NET MVC) tree, e.g. under:

```
\content\data\MyDataFile.txt
```

Requirements:

- I want to be able to specify my path like, e.g.:

```
        <appSettings>
this-->     <add key="MyFileLocation" value="~\content\data\MyDataFile.txt" />
not -->     <add key="MyFileLocation" value="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\foo\content\data\MyDataFile.txt" />
        </appSettings>
```

- I don't want the C# library to be aware of the web application it's being used in, as it is used in other software, and the web application has no need to know about the configuration of the C# library so I don't really want to pass config info between the layers if possible.

Any suggestions on how I can do this cleanly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use `Path.Combine` to combine `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and your relative path.

This will give you a path relative to the ASP.NET root directory (~/) in an ASP.NET app, or a path relative to the directory containing the executable in a WinForms or Console application.

Comment: Just discovered this too but I'll give you the points!  Certainly works in my case (and in a console app I knocked up to test).  Any idea if there are there any cases this will fail?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why not have the web application read the path from the config file, resolve it using Server.MapPath, then pass the resulting path to the class library?

---

Based on your comment, I have a different suggestion: don't use relative paths.

Comment: Yes, I've considered that but been reluctant to do so as it reduces the separation of concerns in my app; it would require my web app to be involved in configuration of the library (which is accessed through interfaces, so could be swapped out later).

Comment: @Tim: Your web app is already responsible for the configuration by the very fact that the config values are stored with the website itself.  Further the web app apparently calls the assembly (it's not stand alone after all).  This is the wrong "concern" to be "separating".

Comment: @Chris: the settings for all assemblies called by the web application are stored in the web.config. That's how .NET works - only one config file per AppDomain. It's reasonable for him to not pass the path to the library, since different libraries might have different paths or other configuration.

Comment: @John: With regards to your first sentence: exactly.  Just follow me here: the assembly already depends on the website to provide configuration through the *website's* web.config file.  There is no additional "concerns" involved in having the site's code pass the configuration data directly.  After all, the site depends on the assembly to execute anyway.

Comment: @Chris: the assembly depends on the current config file to contain any settings. It doesn't know if it is web.config or program.exe.config. No dependency there, except on the existence of a config file.

Comment: Further, by allowing the caller to pass in those parameters, the assembly becomes less dependent on the executing environment.

Comment: @Chris: presence of a config file is largely assumed, so can be ignored as a dependency. Furthermore, having the caller pass the information ties the caller to the specific callee. The OP specified that he calls the library through an interface. Consider one implementation of the library might be file-based and need a path, where another might be database-based, and need a connection string. The caller shouldn't know which is being called.

Comment: @John: I think you make a good argument here.  I just reviewed some of the third party assemblies we use, like Elmah, and it wouldn't make sense to pass all the config data from the app itself.

Comment: Cheers guys!  Have to agree with John's argument about ignoring config file as a dependency.  My main reason for using relative paths is to simplify deployment/testing - fewer config lines to update if the hosting location changes.  Thanks all, I've found Joe's suggestion works for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this:

In web.config:

```
<add key="MyFileLocation" value="content/dataMyDataFile.txt" />
```

In your code:

```
    string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyFileLocation"];
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, filePath)
```

The result will give something like: "C:\yourproj\content\dataMyDataFile" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For instance

In your web.config

```
    <appSettings>
        <add key="FilePath" value="~/images"/>
    </appSettings>
```

and In your code behind .cs file

```
    string filters = "*.jpg;*.png;*.gif";
    string Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();

    List<String> images = new List<string>();

    foreach (string filter in filters.Split(';'))
    {
        FileInfo[] fit = new DirectoryInfo(this.Server.MapPath("~/images")).GetFiles(filter);
        foreach (FileInfo fi in fit)
        {
            images.Add(String.Format(Path + "/{0}", fi));                 
        }
    }

    RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
    RepeaterImages.DataBind();
```