# How can get real server folder location by configurationmanager.appsettings["__"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In real project and real online server how can i get or how can i assign  ?

web config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="FilePath" value="~/Document/" />
</appSettings>
```

controller

```
public FileStreamResult GetFile(int Id)
{
    var model = _unitOfWork.LstDocumentRepository.Get(s => s.Id == Id).First();
    string Cat_Name = _manager.Get_Cat_Name(Id);
    string fileName = _manager.FileNameSearch(Id);
    string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + Cat_Name + "/" + fileName;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(filePath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);             
}
```

I want to retreive file location from real server in web.config

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="FilePath" value="??"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file path location in root folder us same (~/) and if you path inside folder may be try to use (../).

[Also Refer following link for you question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616646/specifying-relative-file-location-in-web-config-for-use-by-standard-c-sharp-clas)