# Get app relative url from Request.Url.AbsolutePath

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the application relative url from `Request.Url.AbsolutePath`?

`VirtualPathUtility` seems to only work with `~/XXX` urls?

Comment: Hi, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681052/get-absolute-url-from-relative-path-refactored-method

Comment: @felipeoriani: That's relative path to absolute (opposite to what I want).

Comment: Is `Request.ApplicationPath` what you want ?

Comment: @PankajGarg Didn't get your point (if you made any) :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
// create an absolute path for the application root
var appUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");

// remove the app path (exclude the last slash)
var relativeUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Remove(0, appUrl.Length - 1);
```

Comment: if the HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath Have a %20 for the Space what should i do ?

Comment: Replace it with a space. Or use `Uri.DecodeXXx()` (do not remember the method name)

Answer (score 37):

Its a little late to answer but there is a elegant solution to this. You can use

```
Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

This will return the relative path of the page.

For example, if the URL is `www.example.com/products?A=a&B=b&C=c`, the above piece of code will return `/products?A=a&B=b&C=c`

Comment: That's not a relative url. It's an absolute path from the root. Would not work for virtual directories.

Comment: But it's what many people need exactly when ending up here :)

Comment: This doesn't include any anchor - which I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative("~", Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
```

For example if the root of the website is `/Website` and `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` is `/Website/some/path` this will return `some/path`.

Answer (score 9):

To do this without using string manipulation and handling the application's relative path I used:

```
    var relativeUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(
        new Uri(context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, UriKind.Relative).ToString());
```

Comment: Why the `new Uri(context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, UriKind.Relative).ToString()`? Isn't just `context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the cleanest way:

```
new Uri(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, UriKind.Relative))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String appUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
 String RelativePath = new System.Uri(Page.Request.Url, "").PathAndQuery.Substring(appUrl.Length-1)
```

Comment: Suppose I have a URL `http://localhost:49484/Website/Default.aspx` This will give you /Default.aspx

Comment: You are doing the same thing as I did in my answer, but slightly more complex?

Comment: Difference is the class and approach and result are same with same line of code as you mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

To build on Ashwin Singh's nice answer - I needed the anchor link to be included with my relative URL, so I just re-added it at the end:

```
Request.Url.PathAndQuery + Request.Url.Fragment
```

So `http://localhost:8080/abc/d?foo=bar#jazz` becomes `/abc/d?foo=bar#jazz`.