# how to get the absolute uri path using c#

Tags: c#

how to get the absolute uri path (`http://localhost/project/index.html` instead of `http://localhost`).

```
WebRequest req=WebRequest.Create("h ttp://localhost");
```

.
.
.
Console.WriteLine("absolute URL = " resp.ResponseUri)

here last line returns http://local host but I want the exact URL path that is http://localhost/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681052/get-absolute-url-from-relative-path-refactored-method

Comment: You are getting into the different perception between client and server.  The client does not know that the default page of the site is index.html.  It may or may not have been a redirect or a default path scenario.