# How convert tilde (~) path the full website url

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the database we are storing paths, like "~/SubDir/2015/A/B/1.jpeg".

How do I easily convert that to my full website url, like `http://www.mywebsite.com/SubDir/2015/A/B/1.jpg`?

Comment: `string.Replace("~", "http://www.mywebsite.com")`?

Comment: Why can't you replace ~ with http://www.mywebsite.com !!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681052/get-absolute-url-from-relative-path-refactored-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting full URL from URL with tilde(~) sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092523/getting-full-url-from-url-with-tilde-sign)

Comment: Trying to use it as the image source for an asp.net image control.

Comment: I don't want to do a straight string.Replace because I could be on the dev machine (locahost) or the production server. I want to know the correct way to do this. Thanks

Comment: It is still a correct way if you have a base address of application stored in config (correct way again).

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating img links, add the runat="server" attribute for the links to resolve correctly:

```
<img src="~/SubDir/2015/A/B/1.jpeg" alt="Desc" runat="server" />
```

This will then display images whether you are on a development, staging or production server...

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the value you want to replace.

You could do it in SQL with the REPLACE() function, e.g.

```
SELECT REPLACE(ColumnName, '~', 'http://www.mywebsite.com') FROM Table
```

Or do it in C#:

```
string url = url.Replace("~", "http://www.mywebsite.com");
```