# Options for storing file path of the component in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, format, filepath, relative-path

I have set of files (which are essentially ".exe" files) that I allow the users to download from my website. To have a clearer picture have a look at the [this](http://postimage.org/image/26h8qf19g/) screenshot (it is just a academic project). Now I have administrator privilege in which I can upload a new software file to a folder (componentsFolder) to the root of my website and I also add the filepath to the database table at the same time.

I'm using the following code to do that:

```
string componentRelativeFilePath = @"/ComponentsFolder/" + ComponentName;
```

I'm storing the filepath in the following format in the database file:
 **/ComponentsFolder/FileName.exe**

What is the difference between storing the files in the following formats?

1. /ComponentsFolder/FileName.exe
2. \ComponentsFolder\FileName.exe
3. ~/ComponentsFolder/FileName.exe
4. ~\ComponentsFolder\FileName.exe

I'm using server.mappath to retrieve the file from the root folder.

I want to know the difference (in this context) between these formats and which one is the standard/appropriate/technically correct format to store the relative paths in database table.

Comment: I think this post will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath

Comment: @keyboardP i think there is a difference. And i also want to know which one is standard/appropriate/technically correct format to store the relative paths in database table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of Asp.Net lets suppose you set your image path as "`/Image/pic1.jpeg`" so the image would be searched in `Image` folder located in website root and in that folder `pic1.jpeg` is searched. If your set you image source to "`~/Image/pic1.jpeg`" in that case as well the image file is read from the `Image` folder that is located directly under the root of the Web application, regardless of where in the Web site the page is located. But '`~/`' this could only be used with server controls.
If path is "`../Image/pic1.jpeg`", in that case Image folder is searched in the current webpage's folder.

As per my opinion storing path in "`~/Image/`" format is a better choice in terms of Asp.Net.

Hope I answer your question.

Comment: whats the difference between the forward slash and backward slash in the file format ? And more over can you please tell me which is more appropriate format to store the file path ?

Comment: what do u mean by "so the image would be searched in the folder containing the current page" ?? can you please explain me more eloborately ?

Comment: Consider this format "/Image/pic1.jpeg", pic1.jpeg is searched in "the folder of your current webpage/Image." Hope you get me now.

Comment: I have checked it, what you have suggested in the answer doesn't seem to be the case ? There is no perceptible difference between the two formats, when i debugged for both formats with "~" and with out "~", the full path seems to be the same when i try to get the full path using server.mappath. I don't understand where does your concept comes into play !!! Does server.mappath execution differ from development server to production server ?