# C# Application Path how to get it to work for websites

Tags: c#

Here is my question, and I have searched this stackoverflow but cannot find the correct solution.

I have an website, that is stored in (locally on my machine)

C:\websites\Website1

in the same folder I have

C:\websites\Website1\xmldoc.xml

I want to be able for the program to find and access the C:\websites\Website1\xmldoc.xml.  I have hard coded the C:\websites\Website1\xmldoc.xml location into my website but I am trying to figure out if there is a better way. I have tried 
Application.StartupPath but it doesn't work.

Comment: A quick search suggests HttpRequest.ApplicationPath.  Is that what you are looking for?  I believe that is what I have used for the same purpose in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, e.g.

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "xmldoc.xml")
```

This technique is useful in class libraries that can be called from both Web and Windows applications:

- in a Web application it resolves to the web application directory.
- in a WinForms or Console application it resolves to the directory containing the executable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to get a local path of a file.

```
string fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/xmldoc.xml");
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath) related SO question and answers.

Comment: "~/xmldoc.xml" would be better

Comment: I tried Server.MapPath, does it need some sort of library because it says Server does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @user990951 - The `Server` object is part of the current HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Request.ApplicationPath
```

or

```
Server.MapPath
```