# How to open word documents in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am under the development of a job portal application.

For that I need resume upload functionality.

Now problem is how can I view the uploaded resume?

I am using ASP.NET with VB.

Answer (score 1):

A good example of viewing word documents on a asp.net page can be viewed at http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Word-document-on-web-page-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Hi when i tried to do this i get an error "This file could not be found. ("C:\...\db_design_for_bbm (1).docx")"

Comment: Have a look at a related post to ensure that the location and generation of the file is correct. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a third party library called "Doconut", here is a demo which actually shows a resume DOC opened in an asp.net website, similar to your requirements http://try.doconut.com/Ribbon.aspx
This could help anyone else having similar requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading document must have specific path.So try:

```
Dim objFile as System.IO.File
Dim sReader as System.IO.StreamReader
sReader = objFile.OpenText(“YourUploadedFilePAth”)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can find much on this topic via Google as this is a consistently recurring topic 
. Here are a few options:

1. Opening/Editing of Word Documents via ActiveX Controls - [Word/Excel ActiveX Controls in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404688/Word-Excel-ActiveX-Controls-in-ASP-NET)
2. Via Office Object Model (basically a wrapper around COM Objects) - [Automating Applications Using the Office Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xatbkd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
3. Via 3rd Party Libraries e.g. NetOffice (netoffice.codeplex.com)

Comment: hi i dont need to edit the word document. i just need to open the word file in read only format\

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

Dim filePath As String = "C:\Attachments\fileName.xls" -- any file format

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath)

Comment: You are leaving lots of these answers which aren't related to the question being asked. You need to pay **much** closer attention to the question before posting any further.