# Is there something like a Url.Content for local paths?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I like how you can get the Web server paths for a file with Url.Content, is there an equivalent for local paths, for example if I would want to save a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MapPath` method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server.  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Also look at [server.mappath(“.”), server.mappath(“~”), server.mappath(@“\”), server.mappath(“/”). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Answer (score 0):

The `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration has a selection of special paths you can use, for instance, you could use something like below to get a path to the user's Application Data path:

```
string appDataPath =
    Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
        "YourCompany\\YourApp");
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually accomplish this using:

```
Server.MapPath(Url.Content("[...]"));
```

Reggards

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get physicalPath?

Then try:
    `string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("/bin");`