# Exception: "URI formats are not supported"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have an absolute local path pointing to a dir: `"file:\\C:\\Users\\john\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\proj"`

But when I try to throw it into `DirectoryInfo`'s ctor I get the "URI formats are not supported" exception.

I googled and looked on SO, but I only see solutions with remote paths, not local ones. I'd expect a conversion method of some sort...

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
string uriPath =
    "file:\\C:\\Users\\john\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\proj";
string localPath = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
```

Comment: Nice! I had this exact same problem and Googled like crazy, this worked great.

Comment: While its a solution that works ofc, there is but one case which it fails. If the location contains a # then the local path will only go until that position. E.g. if your path is file:///C:/foo/bar#/test.jpg then you will get C:/foo/bar instead of what you actually want.

Comment: Hi. I want the file to be present at www.xxx.com/sitemap.xml. This thing is working at localhost, but on server there is no such directory. How can things be sorted in that case?

Comment: @It'satrap Perhaps you are looking for [Server.MapPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/275781/1115360).

Comment: but after using your path, I am creating more folder inside and its not creating the directory. have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493899/the-network-name-cannot-be-found-error-while-uploading-images-in-c-sharp-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
ImagePath = "http://localhost/profilepics/abc.png";
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ImagePath);
          HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same error with the Path.Combine(MapPath()) to get the physical file path instead of the http:/// www one.

Answer (score 0):

```
     string ImagePath = "";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ImagePath);
        string a = "";
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (receiveStream.CanRead)
            { a = "OK"; }
        }

        catch { }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.