# URI formats are not supported in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

I am trying to insert my data in to xml file. the xml file location 
    path: `http://AutoCompleteInGridView%20new1/Design/Pro/pricelist.xml`.
    when inserting my data i got error `URI formats are not supported`.
    It shows argument exception was unhandled.I want to save my xml 
    file in `server system`.these url belongs to ServerPath location.
    can anyone give me a suggestion or links to solve these problem.

here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Check out this question as it may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560664/exception-uri-formats-are-not-supported

Comment: thanks for your reply.In that link it gives solution for local path but i need for server path. can you give me a link.

Comment: The same concept applies, see answer below. You need to create string variable and pass it into the URI.

Comment: I have done exactly like below answer but it shows same error "Uri formats are not supported"

Comment: Why you dont use linq to xml?

Comment: I don't know how to use linq to xml. can you give me a sample.

Comment: What .net framework are you using and is it still the same error?

Comment: .net framework 3.5. still having same error

Answer (score 2):

Use this sample:

```
                string uriPath = "YourAddress/pricelist.xml";
                string  localPath = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
```

Comment: Hi Shahrooz, these one is for localpath but i need solution for server path.can you give a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Jefri,i just want to save my xml file outside of my current folder.Like E:\xmlfile in server system

Comment: Hi Shahrooz, please find the above image and give me a suggestion.i'm stuck here .

Answer (score 0):

you could try with this solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eccd585a-ac2b-4700-aa28-abb4802cd3a5/uri-formats-are-not-supported-error-with-xmlsave?forum=xmlandnetfx

Basically, use

`doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/EEPPriceList/Products.xml"))`

Comment: Please do not "Links only" answer. Post the synopsis of the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
string SavePathUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SavePathUrl"];
string strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-ffffff") + "^" + fileName;
File.WriteAllBytes(new Uri(SavePathUrl).AbsoluteUri + strFileName, Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));
return strFileName;
```