# Opening a file using its URI format

Tags: vb.net

This code

```
FileOpen(1, "file:///C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/Test%20%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%20Test.txt", OpenMode.Input)
```

throws

```
System.ArgumentException: 'URI formats are not supported.'
```

How can I open a file using th URI format?
Changing the filename in the code above is not an option, it is delivered by

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception: "URI formats are not supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560664/exception-uri-formats-are-not-supported)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Dim UriS As Uri("The Uri")
FileOpen(1,UriS.LocalPath,OpenMode.Input)
```