# Using MapPath Method Correctly

Tags: asp.net, redirect, path

I Have Asp.Net Project, I Cant Use Well from Mappath method. when i using this, for example :

```
response.redirect(mappath("."));
```

this line redirect to root, but anything occer for me, My question is :

is any different between :

```
response.redirect(mappath("."));
```

and

```
response.redirect("/");
```

second line working fine !

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MapPath method return the phisical address on your hard drive. The Response.Redirect need the an url. Check it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx