# how to get file names from project/server folder in visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, filenames

so what i'm trying to do is to get all the file names of all the images that are located in a specific folder in my project or on the server (which is practically the same) in a string array.

I tried with

```
Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(@"~/_img/_upload/"));
```

But the array stays empty. Could anyone help me with that?

I'd appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the result of `Server.MapPath(@"~/_img/_upload/")`? Is it the correct physical path?

Comment: it somehow returns this: 'C:\\Projects\\VS12\\_img\\_upload\\'
I don't know why it adds two "//"

Comment: escape char... try without the `@` in your `MapPath`

Answer (score 1):

The below will get all the images into an array (if you already know the directory structure this should help you):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

var imagenames = String.Join(", ", Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\yourdirectory", "*.img").Select(filename => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

In base at your comment, the result you got from this `Server.MapPath(@"~/_img/_upload/")` is:

`C:\\Projects\\VS12\_img\_upload\\`

The main problem is the `@` because in C# means that the string should be used "as is" and not be processed for escape sequences.

Without it, your string value will be: `\\_img\\_upload\\`

For future reading, I would suggest [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275791/1498857) that I found very useful