# Writing and Loading files that are in the C# Project?

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

After much searching and looking extensively, I have a question that is undoubtedly dumb but I'm just missing something easy. I just published my first website and obviously had to make a few changes. I'm using a writer class, before it was just writing to a path on my computer, but that's obviously not an option now, what I'm trying is this:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"~\Files\test.txt"))
```

I just want this to write this to the Files folder in my project. What's the syntax? I'm also using dotnetzip and having the same issue trying a different syntax:

```
zip.AddFile("Files/test.txt");
```

What's the way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Windows (desktop) application, do:

```
Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Files", "test.txt")
```

The application path is accessible in [`Application.StartupPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx), and you can use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047.aspx) to combine parts of a path together.

For ASP.net, you need [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of `Application.StartupPath`:

```
Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~", "Files", "test.txt")
```

Of course since this is all hardcoded, you should also be able to simply do

```
Server.MapPath("~/Files/test.txt")
```

Depending on your needs, you may need to use `.` instead of `~`. See also [Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I should have mentioned I'm using an asp.net project, but I looked up the counterpart and it appears to be server.mappath but I can't seem to get that to workz

Answer (score 1):

Awesome thanks to Ic. for the response. I neglected to mention this is a asp.net project but I figured out that the equivalent in asp.net is:

```
Server.MapPath(".")
```

There are numerous options instead of the . but that's what I'm looking for. Also, I was trying to set this up in a class and that wasn't working, because I needed to do this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".")
```

Thanks!