# The process cannot access the file 'filename.xml' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i have a webservice project c# , when i upload my project @live i get this error :

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'E:\Sites\www.bivolino.com\bivolino3D\bivo\imgGal\ProductFeedBeslist.xml'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextWriter..ctor(String filename, Encoding encoding)
>   at ws_og_bivolinogallery.GetItemsBeslist() in
>   e:\Sites\www.bivolino.com\bivolino3D\bivo\OpenGarments\og_webservice\App_Code\ws_og_bivolinogallery.cs:line
>   1186

in my local (local server)all is ok when i run my project but @live(live server) all my methods dosen't work any more.
here is my code (for exemple for my new method):

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "GetItemsBeslist", Description = "Get a list of GAL shirts", CacheDuration = 3600)]
   public XmlDocument GetItemsBeslist()
   {
   XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("E:/Sites/www.bivolino.com/bivolino3D/bivo/imgGal/ProductFeedBeslist.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
   //E:/Sites/www.bivolino.com/bivolino3D/bivo/imgGal
   try
   {
       if (bRegisterIP)
       {
           try { LogFiler.ToLog("### IP ### - [" + sRemoteAddress + "]"); }
           catch { }
       }
       XmlDocument xProducts = new XmlDocument();
       XmlElement subElm;
       XmlElement elmAttr;
       XmlNode elmValue;


       xProducts.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
       XmlElement topElm = xProducts.CreateElement("ProductFeed");
       topElm.SetAttribute("version", "1.0");
       topElm.SetAttribute("timestamp", System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", ":"));
       xProducts.AppendChild(topElm);

       List<string[]> strarrVelden = new List<string[]>();
       strarrVelden.AddRange(DB.GetItemsBeslist());
       foreach (string[] rij in strarrVelden)
       {

           subElm = xProducts.CreateElement("Product");

           elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("ProductTitle");
           elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "ProductTitle", null); elmValue.Value = "Herenoverhemd Bivolino " + rij[5].ToString();
           elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
           subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);

           elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("Price");
           elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "Price", null); elmValue.Value = rij[6].ToString().Replace(",", ".");
           elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
           subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);


           elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("productURL");
           elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.CDATA, "productURL", null); elmValue.Value = rij[1].ToString();
           elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
           subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);


           elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("Category");
           elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "Category", null); elmValue.Value = "Herenoverhemd ";
           elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
           subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);


           elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("ProductDescription");
           elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "ProductDescription", null); elmValue.Value = rij[2].ToString();
           elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
           subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);



           topElm.AppendChild(subElm);
       }

       textWriter.WriteStartDocument();

       xProducts.Save(textWriter);
       textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
       textWriter.Close();

       return xProducts;


   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return ErrHandle("ERROR - GetItemsBeslist - " + ex.Message, "ERROR - GetItemsBeslist");
   }
```

}

Normally these errors come from unclosed file streams, but I've taken care of that. I guess I've forgotten an important step but cannot figure out where. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You're not disposing the TextWriter.

Comment: never disclose server directory structure "E:/Sites/www.bivolino.com/bivolino3D/bivo/imgGal/ProductFeedBeslist.xm"

Comment: Why are you saving it to disk anyway? You are returning `XmlDocument` from your method and never use the file...

Comment: its a webmethod , most probably multiple request is trying to access the path simulteneously and you are overwriting the file each time , is there any specific reasons

Answer (score 1):

I'd create the `XmlTextWriter` only at the end of the method(when we actually need it) and I'd use a using block as well. `using (var textWriter = new XmlTextWriter ("")) { ... }`
Moreover, can this method be called by different threads at the same time? If so, you have to handle concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your stream ctor in `using:

```
using (XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("E:/Sites/www.bivolino.com/bivolino3D/bivo/imgGal/ProductFeedBeslist.xml", Encoding.UTF8)){

...
}
```

Your code doesn't seem to close the stream upon exceptions, `using` takes care of that. Even though XmlTextWriter is IDisposable it may take some time before it's disposed, you may be hitting your method before that happens.

Also - learn about serialization, chances are there's no need to create the XML manually like you do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`Server.MapPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath) or [`HostingEnvironment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.aspx) to get your file system links. A using statement should take care of the issue.

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "GetItemsBeslist", Description = "Get a list of GAL shirts", CacheDuration = 3600)]
public XmlDocument GetItemsBeslist()
{
    if (bRegisterIP)
    {
       try { LogFiler.ToLog("### IP ### - [" + sRemoteAddress + "]"); }
       catch { }
    }

    try
    {
       var xProducts = GetProducts();
       string file = Server.MapPath("/bivolino3D/bivo/imgGal/ProductFeedBeslist.xml");

       using(XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
       {
           textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
           xProducts.Save(textWriter);
           textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
       }

       return xProducts;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       return ErrHandle("ERROR - GetItemsBeslist - " + ex.Message, "ERROR - GetItemsBeslist");
    }
}

private XmlDocument GetProducts()
{
    XmlDocument xProducts = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement subElm;
    XmlElement elmAttr;
    XmlNode elmValue;


    xProducts.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
    XmlElement topElm = xProducts.CreateElement("ProductFeed");
    topElm.SetAttribute("version", "1.0");
    topElm.SetAttribute("timestamp", System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", ":"));
    xProducts.AppendChild(topElm);

    List<string[]> strarrVelden = new List<string[]>();
    strarrVelden.AddRange(DB.GetItemsBeslist());
    foreach (string[] rij in strarrVelden)
    {

       subElm = xProducts.CreateElement("Product");

       elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("ProductTitle");
       elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "ProductTitle", null); elmValue.Value = "Herenoverhemd Bivolino " + rij[5].ToString();
       elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
       subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);

       elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("Price");
       elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "Price", null); elmValue.Value = rij[6].ToString().Replace(",", ".");
       elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
       subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);


       elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("productURL");
       elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.CDATA, "productURL", null); elmValue.Value = rij[1].ToString();
       elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
       subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);


       elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("Category");
       elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "Category", null); elmValue.Value = "Herenoverhemd ";
       elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
       subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);


       elmAttr = xProducts.CreateElement("ProductDescription");
       elmValue = xProducts.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "ProductDescription", null); elmValue.Value = rij[2].ToString();
       elmAttr.AppendChild(elmValue);
       subElm.AppendChild(elmAttr);



       topElm.AppendChild(subElm);
    }

    return xProducts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also call textWriter.Flush() before textWriter.Close() or as the last line your using block. Sometimes .NET takes a while to write from the buffer to the underlying stream on IO operations on a close and that can lock your file.

Answer (score 0):

you shd try to open the file when you really need it and serialize the access for multiple threads.

rather than opening the textwriter at start of method , open it where you need it i.e. at the end of method also define static global object objLock on which you can take the lock. this should work

```
 private static  object objLock = new object();

 lock(objLock)
 {
   using (XmlTextWriter textWriter = new    XmlTextWriter("E:/Sites/www.bivolino.com/bivolino3D/bivo/imgGal/ProductFeedBeslist.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
       textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
       xProducts.Save(textWriter);
       textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
       textWriter.Close();


     }

 }
```

Comment: thank you all for your reply, i open the textwriter at the end of method and it works :)  this error disappear