# Relative Paths in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to design a web form in ASP.NET using Visual Studio Express 2012.

I need to take data from some `text boxes`, and write it to a `Text file`.

This is a very simple program, but **I am having trouble setting the file path**.

This application will be sent to someone else, and they have to run the project from their computer.

The file I want is called `Database.txt` and it is found in `D:\Project\bin\Database.txt`.

So if he pastes this folder in his Desktop, it becomes `C:\Users\Desktop\Project\bin\Database.txt`.

I am having trouble setting a dynamic path that can find this file regardless of where the project folder is.

Comment: post some codes where you are creating the .txt file

Comment: Where is that file, on the user's computer, or the server? From asp.net you can only access the server!

Comment: I prefer avoiding use of absolute path while writing into files.. You can use `Server.MapPath` method to access your application directory

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
public void WriteToFile(String text)
{
    string logFileName = Server.MapPath("~/bin/DataBase.txt");
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(logFileName))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(text);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! But this is in C sadly, My project is based off VB. Or is there some way to integrate the two? Thanks in advance again!

Answer (score 1):

use Server.MapPath("/") to get physica path of ur virtual directory

see this. post for server.mappath 
[Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put the path in `web.config` file and set the values as per requirement.

Here is some sample code that should help you

This goes into your web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="myFilePath" value="C:\\whatever\\Data\\"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And this is how you read it:

```
path = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myFilePath"].ToString();
```

Comment: What if other computer doesn't have that path/access permissions?

Comment: he will have to share the folder for the user who is running the IIS.

Comment: Then why can't you use `Server.MapPath`? instead of setting manually

Comment: you can use that also but that's a path where all you files(code files dll etc) will be kept. And you should not keep your file there.

Comment: Why? We can create a folder with name `log` or `temp` in root of the application folder. We can use that folder right? and that will not effect other files(code or DLL).. This way all our application files reside only in one folder not on different folders.. 
This way we can reduces the maintenance of file system also for our website..

Comment: I just wanted to know.. Is there any specific reason for using out side folders for this kind of requirement?