# IIS 7.5 ActionLink Resource not found in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, html.actionlink

In my MVC application,`@Html.ActionLink` control works fine in my local machine. The actionlink redirects to the specified action. But when hosted in server, error  "Resource not found. Please check the url" occurs.
 **View Code**

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "ExportToQR", "WPCheckout", new { UserID = Request.QueryString["UserID"], Partnerid = Request.QueryString["Partnerid"] }, new { @class = "btnMakeQR" })
```

**Class for button Image**

```
 .btnMakeQR
        {
            background: url(../Images/Generate_QR_Code.png) no-repeat top left;
            display: block;
            width: 111px;
            height: 25px;
            text-indent: -9999px; 
        }
```

**Controller Code**

```
public class WPCheckoutController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult ExportToQR()
     {
       // logic to get encoding value for "qrcode" from database
        QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
        Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(qrcode);
        string path = Server.MapPath(@"/Images/QRCode.jpg");        
        img.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);        
        return base.File(path,"image/jpeg","OrderDetails.jpg");  

     }
}
```

What is the mistake in my code. ?. Any suggestions.

**EDIT**
This is the url, I get when hovering the button image.

```
 http://localhost/WPCheckout/ExportToQR?UserID=1013&Partnerid=ph111
```

Comment: When you hover the link is the url correct? Whant's the error?

Comment: @StefanoAltieri it's 404 i guess. are you sure the `Server.MapPath()` maps correctly? if not the case you could try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString()`

Comment: @StefanoAltieri : yes. its 404 error. Please check my edit for url when hovered.

Comment: I meant what's the error in the url generated. Ie. what's the one you expect? what's the one you get?

Comment: @StefanoAltieri the url which I get is the one I expected. But why it shows " 404 resource not found" error. The specific method is in controller.

Comment: So the problem is not the action link... I suppose you get the same error if you go to the url direcly...

Comment: @StefanoAltieri : Yes. The actionlink is directed to the ExportToQR action in local system. But When hosted in IIS, this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems that you create a file `/Images/QRCode.jpg`. I assume you mean `~/Images/QRCode.jpg`?

In the first case the file will be named `http://localhost/Images/QRCode.jpg` which might not be readable by the IIS application due to restriction problems. In the latter case it will become  `http://localhost/WPcheckout/Images/QRCode.jpg`.

Refering to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275791/2298807): `/xxx` and `~/xxx` might be different.