# Changing the HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs destination directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, io

I'd like to save an uploaded file outside the project's directory. When I use `HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs(path)` the file destination will be in the server's directory.

For example:

```
HttpPostedFileBase fileurl = null;

foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
    fileurl = Request.Files[file];
}

string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileurl.FileName);
if (extension == ".zip" || extension == ".rar")
{
    if (fileurl != null && fileurl.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileurl.FileName);
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName;
        fileurl.SaveAs(path);
```

The `path` is always in the project's directory.

I'd like to save my uploaded directory everywhere I want. How can I change the code to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it to be the server's directory when you write:

```
     var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName;
```

The usage of

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Points to the directory of the current domain.

Comment: even i save as without ` AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` the same problem persist for example path = "C:/project" the result path is "my project 's path / path"

Comment: Are you 100% sure the path you're sending to 'SaveAs' is a full path (which starts with the drive letter) to the location you want to save it in?

Answer (score 1):

**I utilize:**

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(), filename);
file.SaveAs(path);
```

There is a very well explained post about Server.MapPath() in this stack post: [Server.MapPath() Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

A short quote from the referenced article ([highly recommend reading the full post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)):

> - Server.MapPath specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a
>     physical directory.
> - Server.MapPath(".") returns the current physical directory of the
>     file (e.g. aspx) being executed
> - Server.MapPath("..") returns the parent directory
> - Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the
>     application
> - Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root of the
>     domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the
>     application)

Answer (score 0):

i would use something like this.

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
    var fileurl = Request.Files[file] as System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase;
    var stream = System.IO.File.Create("PATH_TO_DIRECTORY");
    fileurl.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fileurl.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```

if you wanted to write to other than the AppDomain Directory.

BUT the identity of the website must have Write Access to that directory path otherwise you will get a write error.