# ASP physical and virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

This is the first time I make an asp site. This line of code is working fine on my pc but obviously to make it working on the production server I need to change the reference.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Pink\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ManagDoc_Framework\Test1_managDoc\Test1_managDoc\Allegati\" + recordIDcreateDir);
```

I have tried many sort of path combination but I am not getting it right.

I would like to find a solution that makes the code working on both pc, during development, and hosting server without having to change the code.

How should i write the path? Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Comment: try using `Server.MapPath()` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath

Comment: @Oded, thanks for the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method :

> The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the
>   corresponding physical directory on the server.

Additional details on [W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_folders.asp), tutorial I followed, and where I learnt the existence of the above method.

Comment: thanks. this worked: DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/Allegati/") + recordIDcreateDir);