# To store the output of web service in virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have created a web service which gives the data in JSON format, I am going to read this data to create a high-charts. When I coded this web service , I get values in string which I have serialized into JSON format and store it my folder on system, but problem is when I will deploy my web service in remote machine that time I will face the problem to store the file since I have provided local path as explained in below code,

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Json\Json.json", jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings));
```

Can anyone please suggest what I am suppose to do so that I can store this file in such a way that it will be easy to access after deployment of my web service in remote machine?

Is that possible or I will have to create a simple asp.net application and consume that web service and store that file in the folder of that newly created application?

I am very new to this concept hence I don't know about storing in virtual folder or something like that, I got suggestion to do so, It will be very grateful if someone explains me the concept as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways:

1. Give write permission to your application identity to write in `c:\json` folder, which is not a good idea.
2. Change your code to use relative path:

   ```
   File.WriteAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/json"), "json-text");
   ```

`Server.MapPath` maps a virtual directory to it's equivalent absolute directory in OS. For example, if your website is hosted in `c:\websites\json-project\`, then using `Server.MapPath("/foo")` would be translated to `c:\websites\json-project\foo` path.

By default any ASP.NET application has full access to all of its folders.

Comment: Can you please explain me, what the second option does actually, I am trying to read the helping material related it but getting no desired help, I would like to actual concept behind this, It will be grateful of you if you would please explain me about your especially this one System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Answer (score 1):

You can find the physical path to your application by giving relative path something like `Server.MapPath("/Json/Json.json")`

for more information check below SO question

[Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Comment: Thanks..your answer also helped me lot but some one else helped me earlier and I selected his answer, sorry...thanks for this links you provided.