# Could not find path in the web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamwriter

I am trying to write to a text file using`ASP.NET 4.5 with c#` using the following code:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"./Experiment/main.txt", true))
{
file.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + " test");
}
```

And I am getting this exception:

```
"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Experiment\main.txt'."
```

The folder `Experiment` is the folder of my web application.

Comment: When you use a relative path in ASP.NET, it uses the working directory which is not your web root, it's where your IIS is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give physical path instead of relative path, use `Server.MapPath("~")` to get the root path of your site and then append the path of file to it. You can learn more about Server.MapPath in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath).

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"~/Experiment/main.txt"), true))
{
     file.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + " test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Experiment/main.txt", true))
{
         DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Experiment/main.txt");
            if (!dirInfo.Exists)
            {
                dirInfo.Create();
            }
     file.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + " test");
}
```