# reaching different directory on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008

I am developing a project on ASP.NET C#. I need to reach a folder which is located at "D://Records/" I tried Server.MapPath, but it did not help me.

```
Server.MapPath("../D/Records/");
```

How can I reach this location at C# side?

Thank you.

Comment: Create a virtual directory on it

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath

Comment: do you want to access D drive on client machoine or on server? you cant access it  on client machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access physical drives(like `C:` Drive,`D:` Drive ) from the client machine. instead of that create a dedicated folder for your files inside your project `root folder` and try accessing that.

```
ProjectRootFolder
        |
        |
     MyFiles  (create MyFiles Folder inside your project root folder)
        |
        |
        |--- file1.txt
        |--- file2.txt
```

Try This

```
String file1Path=Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/file1.txt");

String file2Path=Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/file2.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give virtual path instead of physical path

**Path**

> Specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.
>   If Path starts with either a forward (/) or backward slash (), the
>   MapPath method returns a path as if Path were a full, virtual path. If
>   Path doesn't start with a slash, the MapPath method returns a path
>   relative to the directory of the .asp file being processed.

To get the root path of site

```
Server.MapPath("~")
```

To get current director path

```
Server.MapPath(".")
```

To get the path of the parent directory

```
Server.MapPath("..")
```