# FileUpload Object Rooted path error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to implement a file upload in my web form, It tried this.

```html
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Press browse!"></asp:Label>
<br />
<br />
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
```

```vb
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Try
            FileUpload1.SaveAs("Images\" & FileUpload1.FileName)
            lbl1.Text = "File name: " & _
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
                "File Size: " & _
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & "<br>" & _
                "Content type: " & _
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
        Catch ex As Exception
            lbl1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
    Else
        lbl1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If
End Sub
```

But gives me an error saying file path is not rooted. I am running this locally at the moment and when I replace the file path with this 'C:Users/Me/Documents/MYPROJECTNAME/MYPROJECTNAME/Images' it works fine. This will go online so what am I meant to write as the file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to resolve the path of your `Images` folder relative to your project physical path (so it works for both locally and when you deploy your app).

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\Images\") & FileUpload1.FileName)
```

`~` returns the path of the root of your app.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275791/3286163) is a great explanation on Server.MapPath.