# Delete file from directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

File is exists in ~/NewsPictures/ my code returns always false.
I want to delete a file that exists in location  ~/NewsPictures/1.png by name

```
 My code: 
bool t = false;
        String Location = "~/NewsPictures/1.png";
        if (File.Exists(Location) == true)
        {
            t = true;
        }
```

What I am doing wrong.

Comment: '~' is not being resolved into a correct path when you use File.???? in Asp.net

Comment: You're looking for `Server.MapPath()`.

Comment: using ~ is correct path while me using in FileUpload @MarvinSmit

Comment: just so you know, `File.Delete` will just do nothing if the file doesn't exist, so you don't need this check

Comment: @Sayse If `File.Exists` doesn't find it then nor will `File.Delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marvin Smit said, `System.IO.File.Exists` does not recognise '~' in the same way that `System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload` does.

And as CodeCaster said, you need to get `Server.MapPath()` to bridge that gap. See [Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath) for more details (and examples) of that.