# Want to Create Directory and Upload the Files in Tree View in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Here is my code to create Directory. It Works on local-end but if I host this web app then will get the `ERROR MESSAGE : PATH NOT FOUND`

```
 try
 {
     if (tvFolders.SelectedNode != null)
     {
         TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode();

         fileNode.Text =Server.MapPath("~//"+ tvFolders.SelectedValue.ToString());

         string rootPath = fileNode.Text;
         Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath + "/" + txtDirName.Text);
         lblMessage.Text = "Directory created";

      }
      else
         lblMessage.Text = "Directory already exists";
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Server.MapPath` as follow

```
string rootPath = Server.MapPath(fileNode.Text);
Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath + "/" + txtDirName.Text);
```

More detail about server.mappath

[Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)