# Using Server.MapPath to locate the correct directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a webapp using ASP.NET.

On my physical hard drive:

The path for my text file is: `D:\Users\(MyName)\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\(ProjectName)\(ProjectName)\Data\TextFiles\someFile.txt`

The .cs file is located in: `D:\Users\(MyName)\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\(ProjectName)\(ProjectName)\Account\someCSFile.cs`

In my code, I have the followings:

```
string fileName= Server.MapPath("TextFile/someFile.txt");
```

The code throws an exception saying that `Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Users\(MyName)\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\(ProjectName)\(ProjectName)\Account\TextFile\someCSFile.cs`

How am I going to use Server.MapPath to make it "go up one level", then find the "Data" folder > "TextFiles" > finally the "someFile.txt" WITHOUT hardcoding the entire file path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
string fileName= Server.MapPath(@"..\Data\TextFile\someFile.txt");
```

take a look at this: 
[StackOverflow Post about Server.MapPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Comment: A virtual path uses `/` as path separator, not `\\`.

Comment: @Guffa It does not matter, it will handle both.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `..` to go up one level:

```
string fileName= Server.MapPath("../Data/TextFile/someFile.txt");
```

You can also start from the application root by starting the path with a slash:

```
string fileName= Server.MapPath("/Data/TextFile/someFile.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know you can actually use `..` to go up one level