# Opening word file content on web

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have word files in my details folder and I want to display that word file in the browser. It gives me **is not a valid virtual path** error

```
string filename = "http://something.in/management/details/" + DS.Tables["Table"].Rows[0]["DETAILS"].ToString();

if (filename != "")
{
    string path = Server.MapPath(filename);
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Server.MapPath(filename) will not accept a URL

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.100).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) for usage

e.g.

```
string filename = 
Server.MapPath("~/management/details/" + DS.Tables["Table"].Rows[0]["DETAILS"].ToString());
```

also you can use other types of uning `Server.MapPath` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)