# How to populate a listbox using a for loop to display names of images in a folder without extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, listbox

The problem that I am trying to figure out is: how to populate a listbox with the names of the images, that I have in a folder within my Visual Studio Project? My code so far:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(""));
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have 7 images in a folder(within my actual visual studio project) and I want the for loop to populate the listbox with the names of the images, but without the extension. I can't seem to figure out how to get the directory to work. If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I am having trouble with this.

After this, I want to use an 'if' statement to set the image displayed based on which item the user clicks on in the listbox, if that makes sense. I do not know the code for if the item = a certain item, I can display an image based on what they select.

I probably worded this really bad, but it's the issue I am currently experiencing, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is this a ASP.NET project? Where exactly is the folder located? What is the name of the folder?

Comment: Yes, this is an asp.net project and I a coding this in C# the folder is named 'images', it contains seven pictures and the folder was created within my project, in the root. I need to display the names of each picture file into the listbox without the .jpg extension, using a for loop.

Comment: You need to use the [Server.MapPath method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to fetch your images directory: `var imagesDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/images")`. For more examples, have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the files from the folder with the 'Directory.GetFiles' mehtod. The first parameter is your image folder, the second is a filter. So you can filter on any type of file you want.

Example:

```
string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(path/to/your/folder, "*.png");

foreach (string image in images)
{
       ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image));
}
```

Comment: I have to use a for loop, I appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: If you need to use a for loop, you could change it by this.
                for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(images[i]));
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadImages();
    }

    string[] files;

    void loadImages()
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/"));
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i]));

        ListBox1.AutoPostBack = true;
        ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

    }

    void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string extn = files[ListBox1.SelectedIndex];
        extn = extn.Substring(extn.LastIndexOf('.'));
        Image1.ImageUrl = "/images/" + ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + extn;
    }
```

Comment: I have to use a for loop, I appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Ok, thank you sir, but what would the path be for the images folder within my asp.net project? I create the folder within my project and added pictures as existing items. Here is picture of what I mean : http://imgur.com/fcSR6eT

Comment: string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/"));

Comment: Thank you very much for the help sir, this is exactly what I needed! Now what would the line of code be to see what item the user has selected from the listbox? I would like to use that to display an image depending on what they select.

Comment: I want to make an if statement that basically changes the image that I have displayed(which I already have setup) based on which item the user selects in the listbox, like Listbox1.Selecteditem = "", but I am not sure of the correct code to do that, if thate makes sense.

Comment: The string[] files is now inside some function. Declare it outside the function like 

string[] files;

then inside the function do like

files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);

Now you can access the files[] variable from listbox_SelectedIndexChanged event like

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(files[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);

Comment: I am kind of confused about what you mean, isn't there a way to just change the image displayed depending on which item the user selects? Something like Listbox1.Selecteditem = ""? I can't seem to figure it out though. I tried to understand your answer, but I am still pretty new to this :(