# How to use (root) relative paths with Orchard and System.IO.File methods?

Tags: c#, path, orchardcms

I develop a module working with files. Serving the files in the themes using tilde is OK, but this doesn't seem to work in the controller, where I process the files with `System.IO.File` methods like `Move()` or `Delete()`. For now I use absolute paths, but they are not feasible - the module should be used on different machines and still stored in a single repository.

How to find which root should I use for root-relaive paths in each situation? If there's no universal rule, how to find it while managing upload/download/viewing of files? Or is it more complicated?

My files are stored in: `(SolutionRoot)/Orchard.Web/Media/Default/_FooBar/` I've tried all the folders as relative roots and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  is probably what you are looking for.

If it isn't, then you can ask the executing assembly for its location and figure things out from there:

```
var codeBaseUrl = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
var filePathToCodeBase = new Uri(codeBaseUrl).LocalPath;
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePathToCodeBase);
```

Comment: Likely to be the answer. Now I don't have time to play with it enough, but I'll probably accept it tomorrow.

Comment: It took me a while to realize how to use it (it's static!), but [HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~")](http://stackoverflow.com/q/275781/1801588) proved to be the solution. Accepted for pointing in the right direction.