# ASP.NET Web Forms: How to traverse the files in a project/server folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My ASP.NET Web forms project has got a folder called "inc" in it and inside there's another folder called "drinks" with images inside. So the absolute path would be something like ~/inc/drinks/.

I'm trying to get all the file names in that exact folder using this function:

```
private static string[] getImageNames(string imgPath)
    {
        string[] names = Directory.GetFiles(imgPath) // <- exception
                                  .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                  .ToArray();

        return names;
    }
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work and I get an exception:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\inc\drinks'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\inc\drinks'.

The value of the imgPath variable at this point is "../inc/wines/", which should work, but as you can see, the program searches not through the server files, but in my PC's file system on the C: drive.
I tried putting "~/" instead of "../" at the beginning but not luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imgPath))`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath) for more details on Server.MapPath