# When to use Server Path

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i start to attach the same file to AdRotator object, it didn't work :

```
AdRotator1.AdvertisementFile = Server.MapPath("~/Data/Ads.xml");
```

Then i used, and it worked:

```
AdRotator1.AdvertisementFile = "~/Data/Ads.xml";
```

Can anyone tell me when to use Server.MapPath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx): The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server.

So when you call `Server.MapPath("~/Data/Ads.xml")` it returns the complete path, including the directory on the server. But in your case, you probably just need the relative path, so you don´t need to call `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: so , how can i know if i will use the relative path or virtual path ?

Comment: Normally, you use relative paths when your intention is to refer to na internal resource, like an image, file or page, and you use absolute paths when linking to another website. [Here is a good link to better understand the difference between them](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Answer (score 1):

The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server