# Server.MapPath() can't go up 2 levels?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been studying [this excellent Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath) about `Server.MapPath()`, and I can't find anything in there that takes me up 2 levels from the current location.

```
Server.MapPath("./"); // this works - current path
Server.MapPath("../"); // this works - parent path
Server.MapPath("/"); // this works - virtual root path (2 levels HIGHER than I need)
Server.MapPath(".../"); // This fails
```

Is there no way to go up 2 levels? (That would be the parent of the parent folder.)

Yes, I can accomplish this by going to the virtual root and then parsing/combining, but that seems hackish. Looking for something more elegant or canonical.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `../../`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In windows there is no `.../` path.

- `./` means the current directory
- `../` means one level above

**Note:** You can think the quantity of `.` are the quantity of levels, but that isn't so.

2 Levels above are `../../`, 3 Levels `../../../` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

`..` goes up on folder, so `../../` will go up two levels and so on.

Note that this will not let you go outside of your site's root folder: if page is "/foo/bar.aspx" trying to map "../.." will fail if your site is at the root.