# How to get relative path of a certain project in a solution

Tags: c#, path

I have a project named **SA.SEPA.UI.Selenium.Integration** which contains a folder called **Json Data Files** that I wish to reference from both a unit test in that project, and a unit test in another project.

[image]

I'm having trouble getting the relative path.

With the following string I've tried to get to the folder....

```
private const string importFilePath = "..\\Json Data Files\\";
```

..however this returns a relative path of..

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Json Data Files.**

How do I get the relative path of files in this folder that will work when accessing the folder from both a unit test in the project, and a unit test from another project (after a reference has been added)?

**EDIT**

Some code that uses the filepath...

```
public static List<T> GetAllRecords<T>(JsonType file)
{
    string filePath = $"{importFilePath}{file.ToJsonFile()}";

    List<T> jsonFileCollection;

    using (var r = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        jsonFileCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
    }

    return jsonFileCollection;
}
```

And the resultant error when debugging...

[image]

Comment: Have you considered adding the file as linked to the other project? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Could you show an example code that uses a variable `importFilePath`

Comment: Have you tried this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)