# Getting root directory from virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis

In IIS, I have my website set up like so:

```
- MyWebsite
    - Images
    - MyVirtualDirectory
        - Management
```

I am wanting to access image files in `MyWebsite/Images` from a page in `MyVirtualDirectory/Management`.

For example, in `MyVirtualDirectory/Management/MyPage.aspx`, I am trying to access an image like so:

```
Server.MapPath("~/Images/myimage.jpg")
```

But after running, the path is not correct. In google chrome I can view the HTML, and it appears as `<img src="../../Images/myimage.jpg" />`. If I remove the `../..` then it is fine, but I am wondering why the `~/...` syntax isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

The `Server.MapPath("~/somepath")` syntax is working as expected. This function returns the physical path while treating the "~" as the root directory of the *current* website. In your case, the *current* website is the `MyVirtualDirectory`, so the function is returning a physical path based on the root of this virtual directory. Check this answer for a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275791/9041254)

Comment: Is it possible to get the code to work by changing settings in IIS, as opposed to changing any code?