# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException could not find a part of the route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to read and parse a `.txt` file by calling it in the project's folder.
this is the read code

```
string[] line = { };
string route = @"~\\file\\" + ".text";
line = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(route);
```

the error comes when it tries to read all the lines from the file, it goes to another route that is the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Files\.text
```

and the project is located on the D drive.

Comment: You need `Server.MapPath` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string route = Server.MapPath(@"~\\file\\myfile.txt");
string[] line = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(route);
```