# Upload image in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I use this method to upload image and save it to a folder i created in the server :

```
public ActionResult Create(Regional regional, HttpPostedFileBase صورة)
{               

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
  if (صورة != null)
                {
                    صورة.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/1"), صورة.FileName));
                    regional.صورة = صورة.FileName;
                }

                db.Regionals.Add(regional);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(regional);
        }
```

and the input is :

```
<input type="file" id="صورة" name="صورة" accept="image/*" >
```

But The problem is when i press submit, the name of the image is saved in Database but the picture is not saved to the sever, i can't find it in the folder that i created which is named "1"

please any help

Comment: `regional.صورة` is set with `FileName`, not the path. Maybe you prefix with the folder, like `regional.صورة = Path.Combine("1", صورة.FileName);`

Comment: @vernou it's not working either :(

Comment: Can you explain "the picture is not saved at the folder named "1", which is the Path."? I don't understand this part. You can edit your question.

Comment: @Vernou i did sir

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        public ActionResult Create(Regional regional, HttpPostedFileBase صورة)
        {               
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           if (صورة != null)
            {
           var fileName = Path.GetFileName(صورة.FileName); 
                صورة.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/1"),filename));
                regional.صورة = صورة.FileName;
            }

             db.Regionals.Add(regional);
             db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(regional);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer firstly, but i tried and the same problem which is the image is not uploaded to the server, just its name to database

Comment: Try to use only Server.MapPath ex.  صورة.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/1"),filename);

Comment: i can't because saveas can't be applied to server.mappath method